# VBA Double For Loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to write a double for loop to extract some output from one excel file into another file.

I have a number of datasets which each have multiple analyses that I want to extract information from. For example, Dataset1 has Analysis 1 and 2, Dataset 2 has Analysis 5 and 6, Dataset3 has Analysis 9 and 10, and so on...

For each of these analyses, I want to call Extract1, the macro which does the actual work. Because the code is quite long, Extract1 calls Extract2, which continues the code in Extract 1.

I have tried debugging this with MsgBox. When I run this code, the loop enters Dataset2 and Dataset3. But for Dataset 2 and 3, it does not enter the Analysis loop. Does anyone know what is the problem?

```
Option Explicit
Public Master As Workbook
Public Source As Workbook
Public IB As String
Public IB2 As String
Public IB3 As String
Public IB4 As String
Public Dataset As Double
Public Analysis As Double
Public Mean_Diff As Double
Public Interaction As Double

Sub looper()

For Dataset = 1 To 3

    For Analysis = ((Dataset - 1) * 4 + 1) To (Dataset * 2)

        Extract1

    Next Analysis

Next Dataset

End Sub
```

Comment: `((Dataset - 1) * 4 + 1) To (Dataset * 2)` having 1 is `1 to 2` at 2 `5 to 4` and at 3  `9 to 6`... math kills you here ;)

Comment: Ah. Got it! Thank you.

Comment: In a related question, is it possible to make Excel loop through a list that follows no pattern but has been pre-determined (e.g. Analyses 4, 9, 24, 30 etc.)?

Comment: If it is a new question, go ahead and ask a new question. But only after doing some research yourself. :) E.g. google `for each`!

Comment: Yep... `For Each` is the right way. Like `For Each x In Array(1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10)` and then just go for `x`...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your related question,increment your loop counter by 1 but use an array that is populated with your analysis number. Note that arrays are 0 indexed by default.

```
Dim aryAnlysis() as Variant
aryAnlysis=Array("Analysis4","Analysis9", "Analysis24","Analysis30")
For i = 0 to 3 
 Call aryAnlysis(i)
Next i
```